# MessageListener implementation in Spring Boot not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, queue, jms

I am trying to implement a JMS Consumer implementing MessageListener in Spring-Boot application but it doesn't seem to work.

I don't want to use @JmsListener as I need access to my custom task executor to run the consumers in multithreaded fashion on weblogic.

To achieve this.

I implemented consumer like below:

```
public class MyJmsListener implements MessageListener {
  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
      if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
          try {
              String text = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
              System.out.println("received: " + text);
          } catch (JMSException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
}
```

AppConfig

```
@Bean
  public MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
      DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
      container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
      container.setDestinationName(QUEUE_NAME);
      container.setMessageListener(new MyJmsListener());
      return container;
  }
```

But this doesnot work in Spring-Boot. Can someone please tell what is wrong here?

Comment: And why wouldn't you be able to do that in an `@JmsListener`? It would be exactly the same. You could even configure a `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` to use your configured `TaskExecutor`.

Comment: what do you mean by 'not work' ? Is there an exception, or do you not get messages even though you sent some ?